# How to stop all asynchronous sinks when using Boost.Log

Tags: c++, logging, lambda, stl, boost-log

I am using Boost.Log asynchronous sinks (see [Asynchronous sink frontend](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/libs/log/doc/html/log/detailed/sink_frontends.html#log.detailed.sink_frontends.async)). To have a proper shutdown, one must gracefully stop and flush the feeding of records to the async sinks. The core has methods for adding and removing sinks, but there does not seem to be a way for a client to get sinks or visit them. The documentation has a `stop_logging` method,

```
void stop_logging(boost::shared_ptr< sink_t >& sink)
{
    boost::shared_ptr< logging::core > core = logging::core::get();

    // Remove the sink from the core, so that no records are passed to it
    core->remove_sink(sink);

    // Break the feeding loop
    sink->stop();

    // Flush all log records that may have left buffered
    sink->flush();

    sink.reset();
}
```

but it takes a specific `sink_t` type. The [asynchronous_sink](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/libs/log/doc/html/sinks.html#header.boost.log.sinks.async_frontend_hpp) frontend class has template arguments for the sink backend and queuing strategy.

```
  template<typename SinkBackendT, 
           typename QueueingStrategyT = unbounded_fifo_queue> 
    class asynchronous_sink;
```

I will have several different kinds of sinks, so I would like to have a generic container that holds them, so I can simple iterate over it and call `stop_logging` for each sink in the container.

This is really a general question about C++ templated data structures that I need to address because of the interface provided in Boost.Log. What is a good data structure to use to keep track of asynchronous sinks I have added to the Boost.Log core? I need one so I can call `stop_logging` on shutdown.

My first simple-minded approach is to have a vector of `boost::any` objects. But that is rather cumbersome and inelegant. I suspect that a reasonable approach would be to have a vector of function objects that are lambda methods calling `stop_logging`. But I get lost in the template types and do not know how to do this.

I appreciate any help.
Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The most direct solution would be to have a container with function objects, as you suggested. For example:

```
std::vector< std::function< void() > > stop_functions;

// For every asynchronous sink you add
stop_functions.emplace_back([sink]()
{
    sink->flush();
    sink->stop();
});
```

In this example `sink` can be a pointer to any instance of `asynchronous_sink` that you happen to add to the logging core. When your application terminates you just have to call all the saved functions in the container:

```
for (auto& stop : stop_functions)
    stop();
```

However, there is a Boost.Signals2 library that [allows](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/doc/html/signals2/tutorial.html#idp394536896) to simplify this process a little. You can create a signal and then connect the functions to it like this:

```
boost::signals2::signal< void() > stop_signal;

// For every asynchronous sink you do
stop_signal.connect([sink]()
{
    sink->flush();
    sink->stop();
});
```

Then by invoking the signal you'll be calling every connected function object, effectively stopping every sink.

```
stop_signal();
```

In either case, you can use `std::bind` or any other means to create the function objects you like. The essential part is to save the pointer to the sink frontend, along with its type, into the function object.

Comment: The line `sink->stop()` gives me a compilation error... The Boost is 1.65.1 - is the `stop` function obsolete? What should I call instead?

Comment: You're probably not using `asynchronous_sink`.

Comment: I use sink, returned by `add_file_log` function... Could you please look at my recent question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54016819/how-to-correctly-exit-from-a-program-which-uses-boost-log

Comment: That function returns an instance of `synchronous_sink`, unless you disabled multithreading.

Comment: How to disable multi-threading? I tried the `BOOST_LOG_NO_THREADS` option, but got a lot of linkage errors, like `undefined reference to `boost::log::v2_st::core::get()`

Comment: You have to build both Boost and your code with the same settings. https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_69_0/libs/log/doc/html/log/installation/config.html

Comment: I wish you provide both versions of the library - single-threaded and multi-threaded