# Force construction of a global object

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2017

Here’s the code:

```
struct S
{
    S()
    {
        __debugbreak();
    }
};
static const S g_s;
```

Obviously, I want some code to run at startup.

This only works for some source files, that have symbols referenced by outside code. For source files in a static library that don’t have any symbols referenced from outside, looks like the compiler or linker drop the complete compilation unit, so the global object is not constructed.

Is there a way to force construction of static objects, or otherwise force running of the code at startup?

I’ve double checked compilation settings for these source files, they are identical, and they are in the same static library project.

The static library is used by a DLL. Global objects are expected to be constructed before DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH call.

Comment: Quite a few related posts over there -----> None of them helped?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Just a single one is about static library (yes, the problem is specific to static libraries). First answer requires #include which I don’t want, second one is just BS (I reliably repro in debug builds with no optimization at all).

Comment: Turning off optimisation doesn't really do any such thing. C++ is an abstraction not a one-to-one mapping to target language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to link "everything" from this library using linker options such as

```
-Wl--whole-archive -lmylib -Wl--no-whole-archive (gcc)
```

or

```
/INCLUDE symbol (vc)
```

or

```
/WHOLEARCHIVE:mylib (vc)
```

However relying on dynamic initialization stage and / or making assumptions about state of global objects during program startup / dll loading makes your program doomed. So you should consider explicit initialization instead.

Comment: /INCLUDE doesn’t work for 2 reasons: (1) the real code is based on templates, combine with mangling and names become impossible to guess (2) That’s for registration of class factories, the whole point of the factories is to minimize my work spent per class. For the same reason I don’t want explicit initialization.

/WHOLEARCHIVE worked, thanks.

Comment: BTW, do you know an alternative that’s not doomed, and not overengineered (like compile-time codegen)?

Comment: @Soonts I've already suggested an alternative: explicit initialization.

Comment: Someone needs to collect all the initializers across the whole library. I don't want to be that someone, too easy to create bugs by forgetting to change that explicit place.

Comment: @Soonts But it is considerably easier to fix such bugs when initialization is performed at that known explicit place rather than when it is randomly scattered everywhere. It will be considerably easier to figure out which factories are registered / initialized and in which order. It will be considerably easier to reuse code in different projects that may need different registration approach or none at all. And it will let you avoid SIOF and fancy build options involving `/WHOLEARCHIVE`.

Comment: It will take more efforts to make new classes, or change registration properties for old ones. Huge source of bugs, especially for larger projects. Speaking of larger projects, that explicit place will create a merging choke point, again people will waste time doing useless work resolving merge conflicts. Registration order is irrelevant for factories, so is SOIF: C++ guarantees to complete construction of static objects before the first explicitly called line of code i.e. before entering DllMain. If you need to use other global stuff in registration, there’re simple workarounds.

Comment: @Soonts It is actually the opposite: it will take less effort to make new classes because these classes don't need to be aware of the registration procedures required by some other modules that will consume these classes; it will be easier to change registration procedures of old classes because these procedures are kept in that known explicit place instead of being scattered around. And it does not lead to creation of merging choke point (remember: class developer(s) is not aware of registration and works independently from consumer module developer(s)).

Comment: @Soonts Registration order is only irrelevant as long as factories are trivial, and there are no simple workarounds for SOIF when it is already in code base.

Comment: They are consumed by the same module. With explicit init, you’re splitting the logic related to the class in two far away places: the class itself, and the registration. From now on you must to not forget to keep them in sync. You can’t even rename a class without breaking totally unrelated place of code that registered it, now that’s what I’d call “doomed”.

Comment: Factories aren’t trivial but that’s irrelevant, they’re called much later than static constructors. Factories registration is trivial, yes. Simple workaround for SOIF is replacing global vars with global functions returning refs to local statics. This will cause lazy init. Obviously won't work for registering stuff, but allows singletons to be used by static constructors just fine, that's even thread safe.

Comment: @Soonts Well, things are escalating quickly on larger projects: today these classes are consumed in the same module, tomorrow that one class is extracted into separate project to be developed by that one guy, in two years you end up with dozen of plugins some of which are developed by people you haven't even met and are used in some other unrelated modules that will require different registration procedure, if any.

Comment: @Soonts As for lazy init / Meyer's singleton - it is exceptionally evil because it takes control over object lifetime. You can find people whining about singletons being bad for testing (just because they have no control over them) all over SO. And no, local statics don't protect from SOIF at all. For example see [Why my application crashes on process termination when file sinks are used?](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_69_0/libs/log/doc/html/log/rationale/why_crash_on_term.html) from boost.log which relies on local statics.

Comment: If you design your software for requirements that may or may not happen 2 years in the future, you’ll end up with overengineered enterprise-grade code. I’ve been using automatically registered stuff for couple decades now, work OK for me and cause very little problems. If the project overgrows them, then it’s time to replace with something else. Centralized initializers on the other hand..

Comment: I never liked boost and never used it. They wrote “There is no way for Boost.Log to influence the order of global deinitialization” but that’s not true, C++ guarantees the order will be the reverse order of their construction. They probably only use the lazy trick only in one place instead of both, the other is a normal global variable.